# Find the distribution function of the variable $Y=X$ when $a\leq X\leq b$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ with distribution $F_{X}(x)$ and let $a<b$ two constants. Define $Y=a$ if $X<a$, $Y=X$ if $a\leq X\leq b$ and $Y=b$ if $X>b$. Find the distribution function $F_{Y}(y)$ in terms of $F_{X}$.

It's obvious that when $a\leq X\leq b$, $F_{Y}(y)=F_{X}(y)$ however I don know what happens when $X<a$ for example, we'd have $F_{Y}(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(a\leq y)$ but whatis it equal to? Maybe 0?

Comment: take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting distribution function of $Y$ has 2 discontinuity points as it has two positive probability masses in $Y=a$ and $Y=b$

For this reason Y does not have a density...even if it is usual in some applications to define for $Y$ a "mixed density"

The resulting distribution function is the following

$$ F_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $y<a$ } \\
\mathbb{P}[X\le a],  & \text{if $y=a$ } \\
F_X(y),  & \text{if $a<y<b$ } \\
1, & \text{if $y\geq  b$}
\end{cases}$$

As you can see, if you want to check

$$\mathbb{P}[Y=b]=1-F_X(b)=1-\mathbb{P}[X\leq b]=\mathbb{P}[X>b]$$

as expected...

---

Here is a drawing of your transformation function (as an example I supposed $a>0$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}$ but this is not necessary, it is only an example to help you to figure out the problem)

[image]

Comment: I think you have $F_Y(a)=\mathbb P[X \le a] = F_X(a)$ rather than$ \mathbb P[X \lt a]$ though it makes no difference if $X$ is a continuous random variable.  You could extend your $F_y(y)$ to $$F_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $y<a$ } \\
F_X(y),  & \text{if $a\le y<b$ } \\
1, & \text{if $y\ge b$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Henry : ops...your observations are absolutely correct. I amended my CDF but now it looks like very redundant :(

Comment: It is not redundant: it may seem obvious to you that there are steps in the CDF and $\mathbb P[Y=a]=\mathbb P[X \le a]$ and $\mathbb P[Y=b]=\mathbb P[X \ge b]$ but this reinforces your point that $Y$ does not have a density at $a$ and $b$, while saying $F_Y(y)=0$ if $y<a$ directly answers part of the question